# On creation of folder in a specified folder create sub folders in the new folder

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm new to applescript and automator.I have explored the different threads at apple but unable to find something useful.
Well My problem is that I have a folder i.e "work" i have applied folder action on it. On creation of new folder at "work" i.e "abc" I want to create three new folders in "abc". Check out my code

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
  tell application Finder
    repeat with this_item in added_items
        make new folder at this_item with properties {name:"Main"}
        make new folder at this_item with properties {name:"Lower"}
        make new folder at this_item with properties {name:"Upper"}
   end repeat
  end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost...

`Finder` must be in double quotes

```
tell application "Finder"
```

Comment: Code is fine but it is not running while creating a new folder

Comment: You might have forgotten one step of the folder action setup. I tested the code successfully.